# How do I customize the message displayed in a users Facebook friend request (invite)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have something like this, and want 'Check out this app' to be displayed in the users Notification.

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
         message: 'Check out this app',
});
```

but the message is not displayed as I want:

it just says 'Kamil has sent you a request.'

http://cl.ly/image/1G3z0Y0h1X0C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, apprequests 'message' is visible only if target user already granted permissions to your application.

This is a known Facebook limitation to avoid phishing and spam.

There was a workaround (circa Q1 2012), which adding **new_style_message: true** to FB.ui options parameter showed it. Some people reported that it still works for them, but (as of my recent tests) it's not working anymore.

Cheers!